# Unrecognized pipeline stage name: '$sample'

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, robo3t

when I run this aggregation pipeline in Robomongo

```
db.getCollection('xyz').aggregate([{$match: {tyu: "asd", ghj: "qwe"}},
{$sample: {size: 5}}])
```

I receive this error:

```
assert: command failed: {
"errmsg" : "exception: Unrecognized pipeline stage name: '$sample'",
"code" : 16436,
"ok" : 0
```

I'm using mongodb ver 3.2.6 and since $sample is supported from 3.2 onward.
(https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sample/#pipe._S_sample)

Im a little confused as to why I receive this error message.

Maybe I'm just missing something small.

Thanks

Comment: Have a look in to the comments of this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23790525/mongo-2-6-1-unrecognized-pipeline-stage-name-out), which may help you.

Comment: Thanks. In the shell version() shows 3.2.6 but db.version() shows 3.0.6.

Answer (score 4):

As stated in the comments of the question. Mongo client had a version of 3.2.6 but Mongo db had a version of 3.0.6.

I used `version()` in the shell to get the client's version and
`db.version()` to get the DB's version.

ver 3.0.6 is too low to support `$sample` as stated in the mongo documentation
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sample/#pipe._S_sample